# Google Places SDK does not return photos for a popular place. iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places

I use the Google Places API, I get photos for the place, but I ran into such a problem that for the very popular location of Santa Monica Pier, Santa Monica, CA, United States there are no photos. I started to study this question, and what id is returned for this site via [Google Places Finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder) and I returned another id, I tried the id which I returned to the web version for uploading photos and the photos were successfully downloaded. 
I got the `EjJTYW50YSBNb25pY2EgUGllciwgU2FudGEgTW9uaWNhLCBDQSwgVW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcw`  place id with iOS version, it's `ChIJm6deTdekwoARTY_RzhoRms0` place id with [Google Places Finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder).

```
import GooglePlaces

class GooglePlacesManager {

    private let gmsPlacesClient = GMSPlacesClient()

    func loadPhotosForPlace(_ placeID: String, success: ((_ photos: [UIImage]) -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        gmsPlacesClient.lookUpPhotos(forPlaceID: placeID) { [weak self] (photos, error) -> Void in
            guard error == nil else {
                debugPrint("loadPhotosForPlace", error!.localizedDescription)
                fail?(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let results = photos?.results else {
                success?([])
                return
            }
            var resultCount = results.count

            debugPrint("first result count", resultCount)

            if resultCount == 0 {
                success?([])
                return
            }

            var photos = [UIImage]()

            guard self != nil else { return }
            for result in results {
                self!.loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: result, success: { (photo) in
                    photos.append(photo)
                    if resultCount == photos.count {
                        success?(photos)
                    }
                }, notExist: {
                    resultCount -= 1
                    if resultCount == photos.count {
                        success?(photos)
                    }
                }, fail: { (error) in
                    resultCount -= 1
                    if resultCount == photos.count {
                        success?(photos)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    private func loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: GMSPlacePhotoMetadata, success: ((_ photo: UIImage) -> Void)?, notExist: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        gmsPlacesClient.loadPlacePhoto(photoMetadata, callback: {
            (photo, error) -> Void in
            guard error == nil else {
                debugPrint("loadPhotosForPlace", error!.localizedDescription)
                fail?(error!)
                return
            }
            guard photo != nil else {
                notExist?()
                return
            }
            success?(photo!)
        })
    }

    func getLocationInfo(_ placeID: String, success: ((_ place: GMSPlace) -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        gmsPlacesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID) { (place, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                debugPrint(error!.localizedDescription)
                fail?(error!)
                return
            }
            guard place != nil else { return }
            success?(place!)
        }
    }

}
```

Please tell me how it can be fixed?

**Update**:
I added these lines of code  in this `loadPhotosForPlace` functions

```
   gmsPlacesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let place = place else {
                print("No place details for \(placeID)")
                return
            }

            print("Place name \(place.name)")
            print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
            print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
            print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
        })
```

I got this logs but a I didn't get any photos.

```
Place name Santa Monica Pier
Place address Optional("Santa Monica Pier, Santa Monica, CA 90401, USA")
Place placeID EjJTYW50YSBNb25pY2EgUGllciwgU2FudGEgTW9uaWNhLCBDQSwgVW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcw
Place attributions nil
```

Comment: Update your question title.

Comment: @BhavinRamani thanks, I updated it.